# Haskell function foldl (\x y -> x*2 + y*2) 0 behavior

Tags: haskell, fold

I stuck with a problem. What's difference between these two functions:

```
foldl (\x y -> x*2 + y*2) 0 [1,2,3] = 22
foldr (\x y -> x*2 + y*2) 0 [1,2,3] = 34

foldl (\x y -> x*2 + y*2) 0 [1,2,3] ⇒ f( f( f(0,1),2 ),3 )
foldr (\x y -> x*2 + y*2) 0 [1,2,3] ⇒ f( 3,f( 2, f(1,0) ) )
```

where `f = \x y -> x*2 + y*2`.

I understand result of `foldl`:

```
x = f(0,1) = 2
y = f(x,2) = 8
z = f(y,3) = 22
```

But why does `foldr` sum after result of each step?

```
2 + 8 + 22 = 34
```

Comment: If you were trying to get the sum of squares, then you want: `foldl' (\x y -> x + y^2) 0`

Comment: Also note that it's generally recommended to always use strict version of `foldl` — `foldl'`, because it doesn't cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the `foldr` evaluation backwards. It should look like this:

```
foldr f 0 [1,2,3] == f 1 (f 2 (f 3 0))
```

For contrast, the `foldl` evaluation (which is correct in your question) looks like

```
foldl f 0 [1,2,3] == f (f (f 0 1) 2) 3
```

If you feel comfortable thinking of the list `[1,2,3]` as being the same as `1:2:3:[]`, this diagram of `foldr` might help:

[image: foldr diagram]

Comment: thanks for help, after you answer i began to understand these diagrams. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Your definition of foldr is a little off. Instead of `f( 3,f( 2, f(1,0) ) )`, it should be `f( 1,f( 2, f(3,0) ) )`.

```
foldl f z [1,2,3] = ((0 `f` 1) `f` 2) `f` 3
                  = ((0*2 + 1*2) `f` 2) `f` 3
                  = (2 `f` 2) `f` 3
                  = (2*2 + 2*2) `f` 3
                  = 8 `f` 3
                  = 8*2 + 3*2
                  = 22

foldr f z [1,2,3] = 1 `f` (2 `f` (3 `f` 0))
                  = 1 `f` (2 `f` (3*2 + 0*2))
                  = 1 `f` (2 `f` 6)
                  = 1 `f` (2*2 + 6*2)
                  = 1 `f` 16
                  = 1*2 + 16*2
                  = 34
```